# Trim not removing end newline characters?

Tags: php

This should be fairly straightforward. Say I have the following code:

```
$output = file_get_contents($random_name . ".txt");
echo "<pre>";
echo str_replace("\n", "\nN ", $output);
echo "</pre>";
```

And `$output` looks like this:

```
PDF Test File
N Congratulations, your computer is equipped with a PDF (Portable Document Format)
N reader! You should be able to view any of the PDF documents and forms available on
N our site. PDF forms are indicated by these icons:
N or.
N 
N
```

And let's say I want to get rid of those two last newline characters, through the following:

```
$outputTrimmed = trim($output, "\n");
```

I would assume, that would output:

```
PDF Test File
N Congratulations, your computer is equipped with a PDF (Portable Document Format)
N reader! You should be able to view any of the PDF documents and forms available on
N our site. PDF forms are indicated by these icons:
N or.
```

But instead, this code:

```
$output = file_get_contents($random_name . ".txt");
$outputTrimmed = trim($output, "\n");
echo "<pre>";
echo str_replace("\n", "\nN ", $outputTrimmed);
echo "</pre>";
```

Results in:

```
PDF Test File
N Congratulations, your computer is equipped with a PDF (Portable Document Format)
N reader! You should be able to view any of the PDF documents and forms available on
N our site. PDF forms are indicated by these icons:
N or.
N 
N
```

What am I doing wrong? It's probably something *really*, *really* simple... so I apologize.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You are probably using Windows End-of-line style.

Which is `\r\n`, not just `\n`.

Try replacing both.

OR, don't specify any charlist (2nd parameter). By specifying `\n` you are saying **ONLY** trim `\n`

`trim($output)`

See the docs here: http://www.w3schools.com/php/func_string_trim.asp#gsc.tab=0

---

**EDIT (from your comments):**

If trim() is not working try changing your string to a byte array and examining ***exactly*** what character is at the end of your string. This is making me suspect there's some other non-printable character interfering.

```
$byteArray = unpack('C*', $output);
var_dump($byteArray);
```

http://www.asciitable.com/

Comment: Can I use `$outputTrimmed = trim($output, "\r\n");`?

Comment: Also, is the style contingent on my server? My server is linux.

Comment: Doesn't matter if your input came from a Windows system. Or a text editor defaulting to Windows EOL style.

Comment: Okay. Also, using just `trim()`, which I think is what you're suggesting in your edit, doesn't work either.

Comment: @Charlie Added another suggestion to the post.

Comment: Interesting! The last character seems to be character `12`, or a `NP Form Feed`, whatever that is.

Comment: Okay, I got it to work. If I remove the last character through `substr()`, and then `trim()` the string, it seems to work. I should use an if statement, though, so that I'm only trimming if that's the character.

Comment: @Charlie Or you can use the 2nd parameter I mentioned and specify a full list of characters you want trimmed. Add "\xC" to the list.

Comment: Will that still trim the `\n` if the `\f` isn't present?

Comment: @Charlie If you specify the 2nd param you must explicitly list each character you want trimmed.

Comment: Right, but what I'm asking is if I have it as `trim($output, "\f\n")` and there is no `\f`, will it still trim the `\n`?

Comment: @Charlie Yes it will. The characters are searched for individually.

Comment: Thanks @b1j, your answer about unpacking the output solved a similar problem for me.

Answer (score 2):

try this

```
   $output1 = file_get_contents($random_name . ".txt");
   $output=str_replace("\n", "\nN ", $output1);
   $outputTrimmed = trim($output,"\n");
   echo "<pre>";
   echo $outputTrimmed;
   echo "<pre>";
```

output

```
  PDF Test File
  N  Congratulations, your computer is equipped with a PDF (Portable Document Format)
  N  reader! You should be able to view any of the PDF documents and forms available on    
  N  our site. PDF forms are indicated by these icons:
  N or .
```

Comment: There's no `$output1` variable in your example.

Comment: Then this is peculiar. I tried your code and I have the same output that I was originally receiving. My original code makes sense, and it's not being cached, as I can change the "N" to something else and it updates... I don't know what's happening.